# Laravel 5 date_format validation does not validate

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

here is input value : `FIRST_TIME_ARRIVAL_DATE_AT_DAW : 2016-21-5 17:21:35` here is validation rule :

```
public static $createRules = [
      'FIRST_TIME_ARRIVAL_DATE_AT_DAW' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s"',
];
```

and it doesn't validatate, it return :

```
{"CELLS_EXPIRY_DATE":["The FIRST TIME ARRIVAL DATE AT DAW does not match the format Y-m-d H:i:s."]
```

EDIT:
here is what my controller looks like:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),BatteryAssets::$createRules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return ['success' => 0, 'data' => 'Input error','errors' => $validator->messages()->toJson()];
        }
```

so `$validator->messages()->toJson()` return the validation error

Comment: Which part fails? The actual validation? The custom error message? What does your form look like? Also, is it required? If so, you should add `required` to the rule.

Comment: I have added the controller code to my question, so the validation rules are not met, even though it seems that I input the right values, and the field is not required but if present ti has to have the format, the form is just regular input text where I add this value: 2016-21-5 17:21:35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
format Y-m-d H:i:s need be 2016-21-05 17:21:35
```

Comment: and that's what my input is 2016-21-5 17:21:35, but for some reason the rule is not met

Comment: @Mikail 2016-21-05 not 2016-21-5

Answer (score 0):

Change `'date_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s"'` to `'date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s'`